Restrict access to specific files in AWS S3 via CloudFront - Allow access via origin domain ONLY
I'm using Ruby on Rails Active Storage configured for AWS S3 storage. By default, Rails uses redirect mode to serve files from S3 but I'd like to use proxy mode with CND Amazon CloudFront instead.
Therefore, all S3 objects are only accessible through CloudFront. For instance,  https://gw1kyxjqeuyzv.cloudfront.net/1xcv15u3rhwqbbxtaal789isvsii. If we want to access other objects, we just simply change the object key.
However, I'd like to restrict CloudFront direct access to certain files. Restricted objects that are accessed directly via CloudFront must be denied while they are allowed being accessed under an origin domain.
Let's say, this is a restricted s3 object key 5qykklai194x5q4kvvmrgu9w76hj. And, accessing it through CloudFront must be denied. Following above example cloudfront domain name, if we parse this url https://gw1kyxjqeuyzv.cloudfront.net/5qykklai194x5q4kvvmrgu9w76hj into browser it must be denied. On the other hand, if we access it in a web page under a website domain it must be allowed. Assuming that the website domain name is https://example.com, and home page requests cloudfront like this <img src='https://gw1kyxjqeuyzv.cloudfront.net/5qykklai194x5q4kvvmrgu9w76hj' /> and then the image should be shown.
I've been struggling for a while, and I am not sure CloudFront using S3 as origin can help solve this matter. Another way to deal with this is also appreciated.
